# Homework help on differentiability of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The problem:

> Given the function
> $$
> f(x) = 
>   \begin{cases}
>                                    ax^2 & \text{if $x\ge1$} \\
>                                    3x + a & \text{if $x<1$} \\
>   \end{cases}
> $$
> is differentiable at $x = 1$, find $a$

The requisite approach is to do
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a(1+h)^2 - a(1)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{(3(1-h)+a) -(3(1)+a)}{-h}
$$
which gives the 'right' answer, $a = \frac{3}{2}$
*But*, shouldn't the correct equality be:
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a(1+h)^2 - a(1)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{3(1-h) +a -a(1)}{-h}
$$
as $f(x) = ax^2$ at $x=1$?

Comment: Is this function even continuous at $x=1$?

Comment: The function should not be continuous at 1 as the left and limit and right hand limit gives $a=3+a$ which yields$3=0$.

Comment: @ArgyadeepChatterjee and@CameronWilliams Got it! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f$ is differentiable at $1$, it is also continuous at $1$. Thus the first condition is that

$$f(1) = \lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$$

which is the same as $a = 3+a$. But it has no solution, so $f$ is not continuous at all. The solution is wrong.

Comment: Is that also why the left handed limit approaching no finite value above?

Comment: Which left hand limit are you referring to? @AadiPrasad

Comment: the very last expression in the question.
Edit: this one $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3(1-h) +a -a(1)}{-h}$

Comment: @AadiPrasad ar, yes. You can interpret it that way: you checked that $f$ is not differentiable at $1$.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks!